# Derivative of matrix product with respect to column vector

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I have the following matrix product:

$Y=W^{(2)}\sigma(W^{(1)}X+b^{(1)})+b^{(2)}$

where $W^{(1)}\in R^{m\ \textrm{x}\ n}$, $W^{(2)}\in R^{(m-1)\ \textrm{x}\ n}$ $X\in R^{n\ \textrm{x}\ p}$ and $b^{(1)} \in R^m$ and $b^{(2)} \in R^{m-1}$. Moreover, $\sigma: R^{m\ \textrm{x}\ p} \Rightarrow R^{m\ \textrm{x}\ p}$ is any nonlinear function.

I am given the following result:

$\frac{\partial Y}{\partial X_j}=\sum_{i}w_{,i}^{(2)}\sigma'(I_i^{(1)})w_{ij}$

where $X_j$ is a column vector in $X$, $w_{,i}^{(2)}$ is the $i$-th column vector in $W^{(2)}$, $I_i^{(1)}=W^{(1)}X+b^{(1)}$. In am basically describing the derivative of the output of a neural networks (feedforward) with one hidden layer with respect to a specific column  of the matrix $X$.
Can somebody please explain me how to get to this result? It is quite confusing to me due to the fact tht the derivative of a matrix product is taken with respect to one vector of one of the two initial matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\bb{\mathbb}$
Superscripts may be necessary in describing large neural networks, but here they are visual clutter and a source of confusion. So let variables with ${\tt1}$ as a superscript retain their names, but rename the others:
$\;\big(W^{(2)},b^{(2)}\big)\to\big(U,c\big)$.

Another source of confusion is that the equation as written is dimensionally inconsistent, since it implicitly uses *broadcasting*. To create a dimensionally consistent equation, an all-ones vector
$({\tt1}\in{\bb R}^{n})\,$ must be explicitly included.

It will also prove convenient to define the matrices
$$\eqalign{
S &= \sigma\big(WX+b{\tt1}^T\big) \\
S' &= \sigma'\big(WX+b{\tt1}^T\big) \\
D &= {\rm Diag}\Big({\rm vec}(US')\Big) \\
}$$
With these changes the equation (and its differential) can be written as
$$\eqalign{
Y &= US + c{\tt1}^T \\
dY &= (US') \odot (W\,dX) \\
}$$
where $\odot$ denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product.

As a final impediment to your comprehension, the quantity
$\left(\frac{\partial Y}{\partial X_j}\right)$ is a matrix-by-vector derivative, i.e. a third-order **tensor**. There is no way to deal with such quantities using standard matrix notation.

To work within matrix notation, the expression needs to be [vectorized,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products)  after which the gradient can be calculated quite simply.
$$\eqalign{
{\rm vec}(dY)
   &= {\rm vec}(US') \odot {\rm vec}(W\,dX) \\
   &= D\,(I_p\otimes W)\,{\rm vec}(dX) \\
\frac{\partial{\rm vec}(Y)}{\partial{\rm vec}(X)}
 &= D\,(I_p\otimes W) \\
}$$ where $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product.

The above derivation makes use of the fact that a Hadamard product between two vectors is equivalent to converting one of the vectors into a diagonal matrix and then using normal matrix multiplication, i.e.
$$a\odot b = {\rm Diag}(a)\,b\\$$
P.S.  The ${given}$ result is nearly incomprehensible. This is a sad state of affairs which is all too common in the field of Machine Learning / Neural Networks. A good book to learn this stuff properly is *Matrix Differential Calculus* by Magnus and Neudecker.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the number of sub/superscripts, write $W^{(1)}=W$, $W^{(2)}=U$, $b^{(1)}=b$, $b^{(2)}=c$. The given formula consists of three compositions: $Y=f\circ \sigma\circ g(X)$ where $f(V)=UV+c$, $g(X)=WX+b$. Hence by the chain rule: $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial V}=U,\qquad \frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial I}=\sigma'(I),\qquad \frac{\partial g}{\partial X}=W$$ $$\therefore\ \frac{\partial Y}{\partial X}=U\sigma'(I)W=\sum_i\sum_k U_i^j\sigma'(I)^i_kW^k_r$$ which is the formula that is quoted.